# Multi processing blocked in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Multi processing does not work. it seems they are blocked.

The output of my code is

```
filename2examples, page=1
filename2examples, page=2
...
filename2examples, page=18
filename2examples, page=19
filename2examples, page=20
MULTI, N_PROCESS=4
pool
```

The code related to this is

```
arg_lst = []
df_y = row_data
for idx, (page, df_y_page) in enumerate(list(df_y.groupby("page"))):
    print("filename2examples, page={}".format(page))
    hw = temml_data[page][0]
    page_text = temml_data[page][2]
    height = hw.iloc[0]["height"]
    width = hw.iloc[0]["width"]
    arg_lst.append([df_y_page, height, width, page_text])

if N_PROCESS > 1:
    print("MULTI, N_PROCESS={}".format(N_PROCESS))
    with multiprocessing.Pool(N_PROCESS) as pool:
        print("pool")
        page_examples_lst = pool.starmap(get_page_examples, arg_lst)
        for page_examples in page_examples_lst:
            yield page_examples
else:
   for arg in arg_lst:
       df_y_page, height, width, page_text = arg
       page_examples = get_page_examples(df_y_page, height, width, page_text)
       yield page_examples
```

The `get_page_examples` is

```
def get_page_examples(df_y_page, height, width, page_text):
    print("get_page_examples")
    arg_lst = []
    for i, (idx, row) in enumerate(df_y_page.iterrows()):
        cur_row = copy.deepcopy(row)
        cur_row["height"] = height
        cur_row["width"] = width
        tml_start, tml_finish = row["tml_start"], row["tml_finish"]
        arg_lst.append([tml_start, tml_finish, page_text, cur_row])

    page_examples = []
    for arg in arg_lst:
        tml_start, tml_finish, page_text, cur_row = arg
        example = find_x_text_and_process_row(tml_start, tml_finish, page_text, cur_row)
        page_examples.append(example)
    return page_examples
```

We can see from the output of the program, it blocked, and do not enter into `get_page_examples` function.

The linux machine cpu count is 16.
On the linux machine, the code will work when I set N_PROCESS = 1; do not work when I set N_PROCESS > 1.

When I use windows machine, it will work no matter N_PROCESS is 1 or greater than 1.

I used the requirements.txt generated on my windows machine to build docker images, then run on my linux machine, but also failed.

Also, no matter the python interpreter on the linux machine is 3.5 or 3.6,  it will not work.

when I test python multiprocessing module, it will work:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.cpu_count()
16
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> multiprocessing.cpu_count()
16
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:
...     pool.map(print, [1, 2, 3])
... 
1
2
3
[None, None, None]
```

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You need to ask a question

Comment: What specifically doesn't work about it on linux when you set N_PROCESS > 1?

Comment: Also, please add [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The example is missing the `get_page_examples` function.